# Angular2 with modernizr

Tags: angular, modernizr

I am learning angular2 and building my own custom components using ng2-bootstrap. I want to use modernizer to detect form input which are natively supported by browser.

I am using webpack for building my project.I have successfully configured that.

What I did till now is:

---

1. Install npm install -g modernizr
2. Downloaded modernizr-custom.js with only form inputs checked.
3. Downloaded modernizr-config.json
4. I did modernizr -c modernizr-config.json to get a js file.ow to use

---

I am not sure how to Modernizr.inputtypes.date in my own custom component?How we can access Modernizr variable in my component?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Follow the steps:

1. Place the [type definition of Modernizr](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/modernizr/index.d.ts) into your project folder.
2. Place the `modernizr.js` in your project and access it within any component using relative path like:

   ```
   import './Lib/modernizr.js';
   ```

Done. You should be able to use the Modernizr to detect browser feature support.

Comment: The definition file has moved to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/modernizr/index.d.ts

Comment: Hi, I put modernizr.d.ts in client folder but I don't know how to access to Modernizr because I put console.log(Modernizr) and it is not defined

Comment: steps are incomplete, expecting a reader to pick up gaps.  it should be from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to include the Modenrizr file in your page, above any of your angular code. It will register itself on the page, and you will be able to access the global `Modernizr` object. No further integration should be nessecary

Comment: I think I have to write a .d.ts file for modernizr.js?Am I correct?

Comment: modernizr does not ship one, correct. DefinitelyTyped provides one, however - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156/modernizr/modernizr.d.ts

Comment: Ok thanks for the above link.It really helped.I am now able to get Modernizr variable.I got another question... Does modernizr detects partail support?Like number input? [link]http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number.

Comment: Like number increment and decrement is not shown in IE but in chrome...

Comment: that would be best suited to another SO question, so that folks can find it easier. The answer is "it depends", and in that case specifically, no. Modernizr can't reliably detect UI details of inputs

Comment: Why there are two versions of modernizr in npm. 1) https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-modernizr 2) https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernizr

Comment: because anyone can register a package on npm. modernizr is the offical package, npm-modernizr is not

Answer (score 0):

Import modernizr like below in your ts file and use it :)

`import * as Modernizr from 'modernizr`';