# Using Modernizr with Angular2 and Typescript-typings

Tags: angular, frontend, modernizr

I am trying to add modernizr support to my angular2 project. I have configured the tsconfig, webpack.config, package.json and build is working fine.

But I am not able to figure out how to use Modernizr via importing in the module.

If some code snippets or configs are required then please let me know.

versions:
"modernizr" : "3.3.1"
"@types/modernizr": "3.3.0"
"@angular/common": "~4.1.3"

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernizr  Check this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701637/angular-cli-error-in-console

Comment: Thanks for the link, but what i am trying to achieve over here is that I wanna display custom messages to users based on different types of supports. So just importing the complete js doesn't helps the cause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107629/angular2-with-modernizr

Comment: Thanks for the link, it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't specific to Angular but what can often be the issue is that `@types/modernizr` will be ignored by TS because Modernizr isn't included in your bundled JS. It's included in your DOM as a separate JavaScript file.

1. Install `npm i @types/modernizr --save-dev`
2. Add "@types/modernizr" to your `compilerOptions.types` in your tsconfig,json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@types/modernizr"]
  }
}
```

3. Add Modernizr to the window

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Modernizr: ModernizrStatic;
  }
}

Hope this helps!
```

Answer (score -2):

import like below:

```
import * as Modernizr from 'modernizr';
```